# SML if and else if // boolean fuction

Tags: if-statement, boolean, program-entry-point, new-operator, sml

I am solving this exercise that takes 2 tupples in SML (int*int*int) (date month and year)
"Write a function is_older that takes two dates and evaluates to true if the first argument is a
date that comes before the second argument. (If the two dates are the same, the result is false.) "
this is what i wrote :

```
fun is_older (x int*int*int_,y int*int*int_) = 
  let val r1 = #1 x
      val r2 = #2 x
      val r3 = #3 x
  
        val t1 = #1 y
        val t2 = #2 y
        val t3 = #3 y

  if r3 < t3 return true 
  else if  r2 < t2 && r3 == t3 return true 
  else if r1 < t1 && r2 == t2 && r3 == t3 return true 
  else return false
```

there is an error in line 10 where we have the "else if  r2 < t2 && r3 == t3 return true " . I am new to sml and i dont really know how to solve this issue .
and also can we return a boolean in SMl and how do we pass on values to it (like do we have a main fuction like in java )

i googled the issue and didnt really get an answer pls help me

```
type here
```

Comment: The syntax is all wrong - throw it away and start over. Pay more attention to examples and your fine book. Forget everything you know about Java.

Comment: To be more specifc, you have *never* seen something that looks like `x int*int*int_`, a `let`-binding that looks like that, or the use of `return`.

Comment: You perhaps want to return `r3 < t3 orelse (r2 < t2 andalso r3 = t3) orelse (r1 < t1 andalso r2 = t2 andalso r3 = t3)`

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues with your syntax. I'm going to guess you meant:

```
fun is_older (x : int*int*int, y : int*int*int) = 
  let
    val r1 = #1 x
    val r2 = #2 x
    val r3 = #3 x
  
    val t1 = #1 y
    val t2 = #2 y
    val t3 = #3 y
  in
    r3 < t3 orelse 
    (r2 < t2 andalso r3 = t3) orelse 
    (r1 < t1 andalso r2 = t2 andalso r3 = t3)
  end
```

But pattern-matching can make that:

```
fun is_older ((r1, r2, r3), (t1, t2, t3)) = 
  r3 < t3 orelse 
  (r2 < t2 andalso r3 = t3) orelse 
  (r1 < t1 andalso r2 = t2 andalso r3 = t3)
```

`||` is replaced with `orelse`. `&&` with `andalso`. The `=` operator is used for equality checks in SML, rather than `==`. There is no need for a `return` as a function returns the last expression in it. The types are correctly inferred without having to be explicitly annotated.

Let bindings follow the form `let ... in ... end`.

Pattern-matching removes the need for that construct entirely.

Comment: omg youre such a genius thank you so so much

Comment: On StackOverflow, it is courteous to express thanks by upvoting and/or accepting an answer. You don't yet have the reputation score to upvote, but you can mark an answer on your own question as accepted.